# How to extract a row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

In every other language if I have a matrix, if I call a mono-dimensional index, the result will be an array.I don't know why in Matlab if you take a single index of a matrix, you'll get a single element, that's stupid.
Anyway in C:

```
mat[4][4];
```

mat[0] is an array.

In Matlab:

```
mat=[1 2; 3 4];
```

How do I take the first row of the matrix? mat(1) is 1, not [1 2].

EDIT: There is another problem, I have a problem with this function:

```
function str= split(string, del)

index=1;
found=0;

str=['' ; ''];

for i=1:length(string)
    if string(i)==del
        found=1;
        index=1;
    elseif found==1
        str(2,index)=string(i);
        index=index+1;
    else
        str(1,index)=string(i);
        index=index+1;
    end
end

end
```

This returns sometimes a matrix and sometimes an array.
For example if I use split('FF','.') I get 'FF' as result, but what if I want to return a matrix? I can't even choose the dimensione of the matrix, in this context a weak typed language is a big disvantage.

Comment: You should start a new question for your second problem.

Comment: For the second question: `FF` is a matrix - though maybe that's not what you mean, so you may want to clarify. By the way, you may want to tone down on your rant. Most languages other than C are different from C. If you don't get how they work, it doesn't mean that they're stupid, but rather that you have been unable to adapt to a new language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to say which columns you want. : stands for all indices in a dimension, so to take first row

```
mat(1,:)
```

It is not stupid, but useful. If you address a matrix with only one index, it implicitly gets converted to a vector. This gives you the option to use linear indices (see [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)).

Comment: More info about the extremely flexible colon syntax is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) .

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri To change the dimensions use the [reshape](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function. You do it without a data copy, that is just how you view your data. Of course, the number of elements in your vector must be divisible by the dimensions you specify. I would suggest posting another question and explaining exactly what you need.

Answer (score 5):

This will extract the second row

```
vector = mat(2,:)
```

And This will extract the second column

```
vector = mat(:,2)
```

You can use

```
vector = mat(end,:)
```

To extract the last row

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

From [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html):

> When you index into the matrix A using only one subscript, MATLAB
>   treats A as if its elements were strung out in a long column vector,
>   by going down the columns consecutively

I just hope it doesn't look stupid to you anymore (along with the right answers from angainor and Marwan)